# Is there a optimize way of reading data from postgresql and perform transformations on that in spark

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, databricks, partitioning

I am working to read the data from PostgreSQL and process that data in spark to perform multiple transformations and then create delta to separate records that needs to be inserted/updated/deleted.
Initially I was reading data on a single task without specifying partition column and upper/lower bound values and it was too slow.

Then I specified the partition column with lower and upper bound values to read the data in parallel using spark from PostgreSQL. I am reading the data on 6 threads/tasks by specifying the value for the numPartitions property in the option tag. I am also pushing the filter down to the PostgreSQL for the filter condition and I can see that in the explain plan in spark.

The volume of data is huge, it is around 120-130 millions after filtering. Once I have the data frame in spark I am doing multiple joins with other data frames. I saw that the task of reading the data from PostgreSQL is happening multiple times when an action is called. I am not caching the data frame as it is huge but I wanted to make sure that I don't read that data multiple times as it was taking lot of time.
So, I decided to read the data and save that data frame content as parquet files in S3 bucket and then read that data in new data frame from parquet files in S3 bucket. Doing this the join operation tasks that were taking more time got reduced significantly but I ran into other issue that saving the data as parquet files is almost taking 40-50 minutes. I am repartitioning the data to 48 partitions before I save it in parquet files.

I am running this on databricks cluster with 6 worker nodes.

```
Driver Node Configuration:
Driver Type = i3.xlarge , 30.5 GB Memory , 4 cores

Worker Nodes Configuration:
Worker Type = i3.2xlarge , 61 GB Memory , 8 Cores
```

I just wanted to know if the approach that I am using is right or there are more better ways of doing the same task in much more efficient way.
Is there any way I can reduce the time it is taking to save the parquet files?

Comment: what always helped me in such cases is to do as much work as possible in the database itself, since you can specify a custom query when you read from SQL via JDBC. But if you want more specific help than that please post your Spark job and maybe some sample data, otherwise it's very hard to give any good suggestions

Comment: @hbrgnr I am already pushing the filter to database and only after pushing the filter the records count are what I have mentioned. Total records in table is huge.

Comment: Then why did you decide not to cache the data? This is the same thing as writing it as parquet, only much more efficient. Have a look at Dataset.persist(), you can control exactly how you want the data to be persisted. If you persist the data to S3, the read and write operations probably take a lot of time, whereas Spark can also just persist to the local disk, which should be much faster

Comment: @hbrgnr I will try caching the dataframe and see if I get performance. Initially i thought about it and drop of that idea but what you say makes sense.